# Apply different CSS to input text

Tags: css

I've created JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fpqwruyd/

html:

```
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan=1>Jill</td>
    <td colspan=2>Smith</td>        
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=1>Eve</td>
    <td colspan=2>Jackson</td>      
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=1>John</td>
    <td colspan=1>Doe</td>

    <td colspan=1>
           <input type="text"></input>
    </td>

</tr>
</table>

</body>
```

css:

```
input[type=text] {
    width: 100% ;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

    min-height:35px;

    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    border-color: white !important;
    border: 0px !important;

}
```

I want to apply different CSS to the input text in my html. The existing input[type=text] should apply to other input texts in my html (not shown). How can I do that? I defined a new class but it's not being applied. Thanks in advance.

Comment: its working .. for me

Comment: `<input type="text" />` is a self closing element, i.e. you don't need the closing `</input>` ... what is wrong in your fiddle? You just can't see the white border on a white background.

Answer (score 2):

try this `input[type="text"]{}` or if it fails use !important in your styles to try.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Check out this JSFiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/sks9bo5u/1/

It demonstrates a few scenarios of combining classes with TYPE attributes to select different elements.

```
<body>
    <input type="text" class="red" value="This is RED"></input><p>
    <input type="text" class="blue" value="This is NOT Blue"></input><p>
    <input type="text" class="green" value="This is GREEN"</input><p>
    <br>
    <input type="button" class="red" value="This is NOT RED" /><p>
    <input type="button" class="blue" value="This is BLUE" /><p>
    <input type="button" class="green" value="This is ALSO GREEN" /><p>
</body>

.red[type=text]
{
    /* This class turns input tags of ONLY type "text" RED */
    border:1px red solid;
    color:red;
}

.blue[type=button]
{
    /* This class turns input tags of ONLY type "button" BLUE */
    border:1px blue solid;
    color:blue;
}

.green
{
    /* This class turns any input type GREEN */
    border:1px green solid;
    color:green;
}
```